# Which book was used for Math 112 at Harvard back in 2001--2002?

Tags: analysis, education, book-recommendation

I've downloaded problem sets for the course Math 112 of 2001--2002 at the Harvard Mathematics Department. In some of the problems, there're references to a certain book, but since there is no syllabus to accompany those problem sets, I'm unable to figure out which book that is.

I know that nowadays they're using Baby Rudin for the same course. Which text were they using back then? And, where can I get complete course materials from that particular year and those following and preceding it?

Regards.

Saaqib

Comment: You'd be more likely to get a response to this question at Quora

Comment: @seeker what is Quora? And, what's the URL?

Comment: Quora is a Q&A community similar to Stack Exchange, however it seems to be broader in the questions it allows to be asked. There seem to be quite a few people on the site who went to Harvard University who may be able to help you. www.quora.com